# onsubmit: return false; is ignored if remote: true in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following form in Rails 4:

```
<%= form_tag("editor/work", remote: true, method: "post", name: "myform", onsubmit: "validateForm()", target:"_blank", id: "editor_form") do %>
```

My validateForm function looks like this:

```
function validateForm() {
  return false;
}
```

Even though it gets called, the AJAX submission is performed. How can I avoid that? So, if the function validateForm returns false, I avoid the AJAX submission?

Comment: Is it definitely being called? Like, you've put a console.log in there to be certain? And have you tried event.preventDefault()? http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to type instead of:

```
onsubmit: "validateForm()"
```

this:

```
:onclick => "return validateForm();"
```