# Confirm box depending on input value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

I'm very new to javascript so don't judge hard (any suggestions or comments would be highly appreciated).

I have a form in my rails app (haml file):

```
= simple_form_for(@book, remote: true) do |f|
  .row
  .form-group
    = f.input :book_title, as: :string, label: "Title of a book"
    %br
    = f.input :pages_number, as: :string, label: "Number of pages"
    %br
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, "Create", class: "btn btn-success"
    = link_to t('buttons.cancel'), '#', onclick: "$.modal.close()", class: 'btn btn-warning pull-right'
```

The action in controller which opens a form:

```
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end
```

The action in controller which saves a form:

```
  def create
  end
```

What I'm trying to do is check whether input number of pages is bigger than 10. **I want to create a confirm box.**

I was trying to save `@pages_number = params[:pages_number]` in `create` action, and use `data: (@pages_number < 10 ? { confirm: "Are you sure?" } : nil)` in the view, but it didn't work.

Do I need to use Javascript in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember that `Ruby = Server`; `Javascript = Client`

---

If you were evaluating against a condition set by the **server**, your code would work.

However, since you're evaluating against a dynamically created condition, you'll need to use javascript to determine whether the value is worth invoking the confirm dialogue:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:beforeSend", "#form", function(event, xhr, settings) {
   var $el    = $(this);
   var $pages = $el.find("input[name='page_numbers']");
   if ($pages.val() > 10) {
      var response = confirm($el.data('confirm') || 'Are you sure?'); // not sure if this will pull the rails confirm
      if (!response) { return; }
   }
});
```

The above, although needs tweaking, should evaluate the inputted value into the `page_numbers` box. If the user does not confirm, it will return, thus preventing progress.

As you're using `ajax`, you could use the [`ajax:beforeSend`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) hook to interject before the request is sent to the ajax driver. If you weren't using `remote: true`, you'd want to look at binding to the `form.on("submit"` method.

---

**Update**

After a lengthy chat discussion, we finally resolved with the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
function validateForm() { 
var x = $('.value').val(); 
  if (x < 10) { 
    var res = confirm("Are you sure?"); 
    if (res == false) { return false; } 
  } 
}

#app/views/books/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @book, onclick: "return validateForm();", remote: true do |f| %>
```

We also used [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245535/onsubmit-return-false-is-ignored-if-remote-true-in-rails-4).

Comment: Can you explain what this line `if (!response) { return; } ` does?

Comment: It shows me a confirm box, but when I press 'cancel' - the book is still going to be created

Comment: If the response is false, return. Return basically quits the current function

Comment: okay, so at least we have some progress. Can we go to chat about it, there are some things I need to confirm (no pun intended)?

Comment: Yep let me see about it

Comment: got a link for the chat?

Answer (score 1):

For Rails form, while defining input numeric fields, we can able to set numeric values range that the field can accept.

### :min - The minimum acceptable value. :max - The maximum acceptable value.

The above attributes can be used for numerical input field in rails to control the value range.

Which is equivalent to

```html
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" max="9" type="number" />
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but my condition is a bit more complicated, I wrote a simple example for people to understand my question